# How could I make image button and switch to another screen if the image is touch in LibGdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

This is my second game application using LibGdx framework and this is my first time to use a framework in android. I'm trying to understand how to use it.I have already done with the design in the main menu and my problem is the functionality of each button to switch screen. Any link tutorial or sample codes are much appreciated thank you and advance

Here is my code

MainScreen.java

```
public class MainScreen  extends ApplicationAdapter implements Screen {
//Screen Size
private static final int WIDTH= 720;
private static final int HEIGHT= 1280;
Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;
private Stage stage;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;
private ImageButton playBtn;
private Texture Background,logo,exit,credits,help,option,play;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite sprite;

MyGdxGame game;
public MainScreen(final MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;

    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backgroundimage.png")); //background image
    //Menu Buttons
    exit  =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/exit.png"));
    logo =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/logo.png"));
    option =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/options.png"));
    help =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/help.png"));
    credits =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/credits.png"));

    play =  new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("menu/play.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(play);
    sprite.setPosition(130,360);
    sprite.setSize(0,0);
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(play);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    playBtn = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up

    stage.addActor(playBtn); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    playBtn.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Button Pressed");
            game.setScreen(new IngamedayOne());

        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(playBtn);

}



@Override
public  void create(){

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //Start taking input from the ui
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
//        viewport.update(width, height);
}
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen

    spriteBatch.begin();

    spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
    spriteBatch.draw(exit,590,1140);
    spriteBatch.draw(logo,125,600);
    spriteBatch.draw(play,130,360);
    spriteBatch.draw(option,170,100);
    spriteBatch.draw(help,350,100);
    spriteBatch.draw(credits,470,100);

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); //Perform ui logic
    spriteBatch.end();
    //stage.draw(); //Draw the ui

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    Background.dispose();
    logo.dispose();
    exit.dispose();

}
}
```

My Second Screen

```
 public class IngamedayOne extends ApplicationAdapter implements Screen {
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 5, FRAME_ROWS = 1;
private boolean peripheralAvailable;
// Objects used
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
private Texture cat ,left_paw,right_paw,progressbar_background,progressbar_knob,pause,meter;
Texture carpet,desk,plants,square_carpet,shoes;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite sprite;
private  Texture Background;
Viewport viewport;
private Camera camera;
private Stage stage;
// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;
//Screen Size
private static final int WIDTH= 720;
private static final int HEIGHT= 1280;

public IngamedayOne() {

}

public IngamedayOne(MyGdxGame game) {

}


@Override
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    // Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("cat.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(cat);
    sprite.setPosition(0,0);
    sprite.setSize(0,0);

    peripheralAvailable = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer);

    camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    viewport = new ScreenViewport(camera);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    //Display Items
    carpet = new Texture("equip/carpet2.png");
    desk = new Texture("equip/Desk.png");

    square_carpet = new Texture("equip/Carpet.png");
    plants = new Texture("equip/Plants.png");
    shoes = new Texture("equip/Shoes.png");
    // Progressbar
     progressbar_background = new Texture("progression_map.png");
     progressbar_knob = new Texture("cat_head.png");
    //pause
     pause = new Texture("pause.png");
     meter = new Texture("meter.png");
    //background
    Background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("floor.png")); //File from assets folder
    //button controller
    left_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(left_paw);
    right_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(right_paw);


    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(cat, cat.getWidth() / FRAME_COLS, cat.getHeight()/ FRAME_ROWS);
    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.
    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.200f, walkFrames);
    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;
}
@Override
public void show() {

}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
@Override
public void render() {
    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    // Get current frame of animation for the current stateTime
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.getProjectionMatrix().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    spriteBatch.draw(Background,0,0);
    spriteBatch.draw(square_carpet,150,2,408,800);
    spriteBatch.draw(carpet,230,980,250,260);
    spriteBatch.draw(desk,10,1150,160,260);
    spriteBatch.draw(plants,500,700,200,260);
    spriteBatch.draw(shoes,300,500,110,110);

    spriteBatch.draw(meter,190,990);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_background,20,1170);
    spriteBatch.draw(progressbar_knob,18,1170);
    spriteBatch.draw(pause,580,1150);

    spriteBatch.draw(left_paw,10,25);
    spriteBatch.draw(right_paw,517,25);

    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, 260, 120  ); // Draw current frame at (50, 50)
    spriteBatch.end();

    stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
    stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all

}
@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    cat.dispose();
    left_paw.dispose();
    right_paw.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    Background.dispose();
    progressbar_background.dispose();
    progressbar_knob.dispose();


}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your game should possess only one `ApplicationListener`(called when your application created).

Let's suppose that is your `MainScreen` which extends ApplicationAdapter(Adapter class of ApplicationListener interface), then not extend your `IngamedayOne` class again by `ApplicationAdapter`. You only need to implement with `Screen` interface.

```
 public class IngamedayOne implements Screen {


 }
```

`create()` method comes from `ApplicationListener` interface so migrate your code that in inside `create()` method to `show()`.

Take a look of this wiki for more clearance.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending-the-simple-game

Answer (score 0):

You should create actors to add to your stage (in this case buttons, like an ImageButton)
and then use the `setScreen()` function to change screens on button presses `addClickListener()`

You can read more about it here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d